# Bigquery data transfer service for adwords

Tags: google-bigquery

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../platform-engineering.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
                       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatform.read-only"
));


$http = $client->authorize();


$body = '{"dataSourceId": "adwords","destinationDatasetId": "adwords","displayName": "testing","params": {"customer_id": "42342423432"}, "dataRefreshWindowDays": 3,"disabled": false, "datasetRegion":"US"}';
$resp = $http->request("POST", "https://content-bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/platform-engineering/transferConfigs", [
    'body' => $body,
    'headers' => array('content-type' => 'application/json')
]);
print_r($resp->getBody()->getContents());
```

Response as below :

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
>       "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   } }

CURL command-line not working either:

```
curl -H "Content‐Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN" -d '{"dataSourceId": "adwords","destinationDatasetId": "adwords","displayName": "mauliktestng","params": {"customer_id": "4729344234"}}' https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/platform-engineering/transferConfigs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing body to this:

```
$body = '{"dataSourceId": "adwords","destinationDatasetId":
"adwords","displayName": "testing","params": {"fields": {"key": 
"customer_id", "value": {"string_value": "42342423432"}}}, 
"dataRefreshWindowDays": 3,"disabled": false, "datasetRegion":"US"}';
```